# About dlclose with a bundle on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, constructor, bundle, dylib

*This is about Jailbreak development. I'm not building for the App Store as this obviously wouldn't be accepted.*

On iOS, i understand that once loaded, a dynamic library (.dylib) cannot be unloaded, but i read that bundles (their executables compiled with -bundle) can be.

In my project, these bundles are loaded/unloaded as needed every so often.

My `__attribute__((constructor))` is being called when i dlopen the bundle. However my `__attribute__((destructor))` when i dlclose, is not.

Why isn't the bundle being unloaded? dlclose is returning 0.

Comment: Hmm. For testing purposes, two calls to dlclose cause the destructor to be called. As i only called dlopen once, i'm guessing the system incremented the reference count again for some reason?